# Is using a HashMap the best way to calculate the price of a part that has multiple sub parts?

Tags: java, hashmap, sum, key

> **Question:** Write a program that calculates the price of a part. This part has multiple sub-parts with their own respective cost. Would using a HashMap be the best way to do this?
>
> Here's what I have:

```
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.Set;
import java.text.NumberFormat;

public class RocketStructure {

 public static void main(String args[]) {

   /*Declare HashMap and Formatter*/
   HashMap<String, Double> hmap = new HashMap<String, Double>();
   NumberFormat formatter = NumberFormat.getCurrencyInstance();

   /*Adding elements to HashMap (Name, Price)*/
   hmap.put("Nose Cone", 1233863.45);
   hmap.put("Frame", 76495.26);
   hmap.put("Pumps", 4679358.25);
   hmap.put("Fin", 467945.25);
   hmap.put("Nozzle", 46235.72);

   /*HashMap Size and Part Information*/
   System.out.println("Rocket Structure | Total Parts: " +hmap.size());
   System.out.println("----------------------------------");

   /*Display content using iterator*/
   Set set = hmap.entrySet();
   Iterator iterator = set.iterator();
   while(iterator.hasNext()) {
      Map.Entry mentry = (Map.Entry)iterator.next();
      System.out.print(mentry.getKey() + " | Cost: ");
      System.out.println(formatter.format(mentry.getValue()));
   }

   /*Calculate total value of all sub parts*/
   double sum = 0f;
   for (double value : hmap.values()) {
      sum += value;
   }
   System.out.println("----------------------------------");
   System.out.println("Total Cost: " +formatter.format(sum));
 }
}
```

> **Result:**
>
> Rocket Structure - Total Parts: 5
>
> ---
>
> Frame | Cost: $76,495.26
>
> Nose Cone | Cost: $1,233,863.45
>
> Pumps | Cost: $4,679,358.25
>
> Nozzle | Cost: $46,235.72
>
> Fin | Cost: $467,945.25
>
> ---
>
> Total Cost: $6,503,897.93

Comment: I don't see any problem using `HashMap` here.

Comment: And please note the updates I added to my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The real answer here: create a **class** that represents a product. And then that `Product` class could have a reference to some children, that are `Products` as well. Then you could do something like:

```
class Product {
  List<Product> children ...
  double basePrice ...

  Product(double basePrice) { ...

  Product(List<Product> children) { ...

  double getPrice() { 
    if (children.isEmpty()) return basePrice;
    else return SUM over getPrice() called on each child
```

Meaning: when a product isn't made up of other products, it has a fixed base price. But if a product consists of other products, then its price is computed from the children.

The key point here: the relation between price and product should be made explicit. Ideas to use different lists, or a map ... are fine for a first draft version. But in any realistic scenario, you want to really **model** such relationships. And in good OOP, the key thing to model is: creating appropriate class structures!

And further thinking: actually you would turn to polymorphism here. You start with an abstract base Product class that has an abstract getPrice() method. Then you create two subclasses: one with a fixed price. And one that contains child products - where the price is the sum of the child prices.

Comment: Thank you very much for this sophisticated answer.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, or you can use 2 separate List. 
One is for object the other for price. And you work with index like : 
Object[i]
Price[i]
you see what I mean ? 
Hopefully I helped a bit you

Comment: Great, thank you. This question is asked in a whiteboard interview and I wasn't sure if a `HashMap` solution would be accepted.

Comment: This is really the opposite of "good practice". You are introducing an *implicit* relation between two lists. When there is such an important relation between product and price, then using **two** lists and "joining" them via "the same index" is not a good idea.

Answer (score 1):

Yup.
HashMap's are known for their 'Key-Value Pairs', and using them in this particular scenario would be the best solution here, in order to avoid the usage or multiple singular collections and maintaining the index values.

Opmtimality, this is. :)

Thanks.